# The crickets I want to feed my gecko escaped, what to do?

Tags: crickets

So I bought "ca. 40 crickets medium size" and a cricket home (small box out of plastics). While moving the crickets from one box into the other, some braver than me escaped. Now I find them one by one, but I have no clue, how much exactly escaped. What can I do to trap them? If trapping is not possible, where should I search for them? Do they climb into the kitchen's food-storage?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to built a trap to catch them alive from a bottle (cut into two halfs, turn upper half with bottle's neck and stuck it into the bottom half, add some tasty banana before). It did not work. Could be, that I built it wrong (the opening was some centimeter in the air instead to lay flat on the ground).

Instead we had some funny evenings (crickets are most active at dawn and night) crawling on the floors of different rooms catching them with glasses and cups and cardboard sheets.

They were wandering from the room with the terrarium out of the door and right into the warm and humid bathroom, or left downstairs into the warm livingroom. Also I found some downstairs in the kitchen. But not in the food storage. Instead they climbed into the rubish bin.

We then added some sticky traps (bought, not built) in bathroom and kitchen. There were only 4 trapped (all the others we catched alive).

In total the entertainment lasted around one week, with around 20 crickets over the first 3 evenings, and maybe 8 in sum the other days.

Now, nearly 4 weeks later, we trapped a really big one, but I think it is from the new group already... First time I handle them, so I am still astonished how fast and "slim" they are to escape.